# VS Code code indentation

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, optimization

I want to ask you if you how can you indent a closing tag or bracket from keyboard. Example :

```
<div class="row collapsed text-center back-top">
<isif condition="${pdict.grid_columns == 4}">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</isif>
<div class="col-sm-12 ${pdict.grid_columns == 4 ? 'col-md-10' : ''}"></div>
    <a href="${'#'}" id="back-top" class="product-return-link flex">
        ${Resource.msg('global.backtotop', 'locale', null)} <span class="icon icon-arrow-generic"></span>
    </a>
```

I want this div line: `<div class="col-sm-12 ${pdict.grid_columns == 4 ? 'col-md-10' : ''}"></div>` to have the  properly going under the last div without me pressing a lot of enters and tabs to indent the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move to line in question.
2. Press HOME.
3. Press TAB.